# Spring Security Java Config without Forcing Auth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am having a difficult time figuring out how to wire up spring security without forcing authentication. My specific app does not require the user to authenticate but the user can authenticate if they want.

I currently have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter set up that you can see at the end of this post. With this setup I'm getting a 403 on all /api/* requests and /j_spring_security_check.

Could someone please help me either fix my existing config or point me to a working example that accomplishes this?

Every example I see out there seems to require the user to authenticate and if they don't it throws a 403. In my app, I'm just using it to establish a session and at this point all users should be able to access all end points regardless of if they are authenticated or not.

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ItAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/successful.html")
                .loginPage("/#login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/successful.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not what you want exactly but the following link might help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454078/spring-boot-with-spring-security-j-spring-security-check-not-allowed/29466411#29466411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-spring-security-example) Spring Security application we built with [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) support. In this example, the home screen does not require authentication. Furthermore, the information that is displayed there is dynamically calculated based on whether the user is authenticated or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement, you can use the anonymous authentication.
The documentation can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRonvKvMZKXonjHpfsX56e8rWaaylMI%2F0ER3fOvrPUfGjI4ARMNqI%2BSLDwEYGJlv6SgFTLLAMal10LgNWxg%3D#anonymous)